# Type variables, method inlining and "Bad return type in lambda expression"

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am playing with the new Java 8 features: lambdas, default and static methods in interfaces.

This code works fine:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Comparator<T> {
    int compare(T a, T b);

    static <T> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
        return (a, b) -> f.apply(a).compareTo(f.apply(b));
    }

    default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<T> comp) {
        return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comp.compare(a, b) : compare(a, b);
    }

    default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
        return thenComparing(comparing(f));
    }
}
```

Hower if I inline `thenComparing(Comparator<T> comp)` into `thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f)`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Comparator<T> {
    int compare(T a, T b);

    static <T> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
        return (a, b) -> f.apply(a).compareTo(f.apply(b));
    }

    default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
        return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comparing(f) : compare(a, b);
    }
}
```

the compilation fails with:

```
error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
  return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comparing(f) : compare(a, b);
                                                       ^
bad type in conditional expression
  no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Comparator<T> conforms to int
where T is a type-variable:
  T extends Object declared in method <T>comparing(Function<T,Comparable>)
```

Why?

---

Another version without using `Comparable` as a raw-type:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Comparator<T> {
    int compare(T a, T b);

    static <T, U extends Comparable<U>> Comparator<T> comparing(Function<T, U> f) {
        return (a, b) -> f.apply(a).compareTo(f.apply(b));
    }

    default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<T> comp) {
        return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comp.compare(a, b) : compare(a, b);
    }

    default <V extends Comparable<V>> Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, V> f) {
        return thenComparing(comparing(f));
    }
}
```

Comment: …but you know that the [`Comparator` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Comparator.html) already exists and that you could look there, [how to do it right](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Comparator.java?av=f#262) regarding the generic signature and also, that [there’s nothing wrong with using a local variable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Comparator.java#213) to avoid calling `compare(a,b)` twice?

Comment: Yes, I know. As I have written in the first line, I was studying lambdas, not writing production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inlining

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<T> comp) {
    return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comp.compare(a, b) : compare(a, b);
}
```

into

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
    return thenComparing(comparing(f));
}
```

leads to

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
    return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comparing(f).compare(a, b) : compare(a, b);
}
```

and not to

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
    return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comparing(f) : compare(a, b);
}
```

Comment: <facepalm>, somehow the compilation error did put me on that track, thanks

Answer (score 5):

This can't work because:

- `comparing(f)` returns a `Comparator<T>`
- `compare(a, b)` returns an `int`

So the types are not compatible in the ternary expression:

```
(a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comparing(f) : compare(a, b);
                               ^----------^   ^-----------^
                               Comparator<T>       int
```

What you want is to call `.compare(a, b)` on the next to compare comparator, if the first one returned equal items:

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f) {
    return (a, b) -> compare(a, b) == 0 ? comparing(f).compare(a, b) : compare(a, b);
}
```

---

As a side-note, you are using `Comparable` as a raw-type. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1743880).

Comment: If the `compare(a, b)` returns an int, shouldn't you change the `thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f)` signature to `default int thenComparing(Function<T, Comparable> f)`?

Comment: @sedulam No, because the comparator is `(a, b) -> someint`